# TeamCity: retry trigger's retry number

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I am using TeamCity's retry trigger to rebuild my target if initial cron trigger has failed. However I would like to know exact retry number in the target. Is it possible to do ?
Seems there is no way to provide this number from teamcity itself.

Cheers.